# To check whether a word is in file or not using javascript for huge entries

Tags: javascript

I need a functionality for spellchecker. On typing the wrong words need to be underlined. I have a file which contains the words of about 200 000 entries. I need to check whether each and every word typed by the user is present in file or not. How can i achieve it without affecting the performance. I have used an array based approach previously

```
        jQuery.get('SpellCheck.txt', function (data) {
             var Values = data.split('\n');
            for (var i = 0; i < Values.length; i++)
                TextFile.push(Values[i]);
        });
    });
    var TextFile = new Array();
```

This is for checking the word is in array or not, but this is very slow

```
     if ($.inArray(TextFile, 'Word') > -1)
```

Comment: I have done an array based approach. But it is very slow.

Comment: you can use javascript library for this

Comment: http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

Comment: No we need to create our own spellchecker without any plugin

Comment: @Vaishali, Are you using `contenteditable` ?

Comment: Yes I am using content editable